# Log4j2 logs into user home folder

Tags: java, log4j, log4j2

I'm trying to save log4j2 logs into user home folder because the user has not right to write where the application is installed.

This is the relevant part of my log4j settings. Unfortunately it doesn't resolve user.home and so it creates the folder $user.home where the application is running.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration name="defaultConfiguration" status="warn" strict="true" monitorInterval="270">
    <properties>        
        <property name="patternlayout">%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
        </property>
        <property name="filename">${user.home}/niro/logs/niroDesk.log</property>
        <property name="filenamePattern">${user.home}/niro/logs/niroDesk.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz
        </property>
    </properties>

    <appenders>
        <appender name="Console" type="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
            <layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${patternlayout}" />
        </appender>

        <!-- Log su file ogni giorno, e mantenimento degli ultimi 5 files -->
        <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="${filenamePattern}" bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
            <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" />
            <Policies>
                <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
            </Policies>
            <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
                <Delete basePath="${user.home}/niro/logs" maxDepth="2">
                    <IfFileName glob="niroDesk*.log.gz" />
                    <IfLastModified age="7d" />
                </Delete>
            </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
        </RollingFile>

        <appender name="AsyncFile" type="async" blocking="true" bufferSize="128">
            <appender-ref ref="File" />
        </appender>
    </appenders>
    <loggers>
        <root level="error">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
            <appender-ref ref="AsyncFile" />
        </root>
        <logger level="warn" name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
            <appender-ref ref="Console" />
            <appender-ref ref="AsyncFile" />
        </logger>   
    </loggers>
</configuration>
```

%d{dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss} %5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
        
        ${user.home}/niro/logs/niroDesk.log
        ${user.home}/niro/logs/niroDesk.log-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log.gz

```
<appenders>
    <appender name="Console" type="Console" target="SYSTEM_OUT">
        <layout type="PatternLayout" pattern="${patternlayout}" />
    </appender>

    <!-- Log su file ogni giorno, e mantenimento degli ultimi 5 files -->
    <RollingFile name="File" fileName="${filename}" filePattern="${filenamePattern}" bufferedIO="true" immediateFlush="true" append="true">
        <PatternLayout pattern="${patternlayout}" />
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
        </Policies>
        <DefaultRolloverStrategy>
            <Delete basePath="${user.home}/niro/logs" maxDepth="2">
                <IfFileName glob="niroDesk*.log.gz" />
                <IfLastModified age="7d" />
            </Delete>
        </DefaultRolloverStrategy>
    </RollingFile>

    <appender name="AsyncFile" type="async" blocking="true" bufferSize="128">
        <appender-ref ref="File" />
    </appender>
</appenders>
<loggers>
    <root level="error">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="AsyncFile" />
    </root>
    <logger level="warn" name="org.springframework" additivity="false">
        <appender-ref ref="Console" />
        <appender-ref ref="AsyncFile" />
    </logger>   
</loggers>
```

There is a way to solve this issue?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

I solved the issue. You sould use `${sys:user.home}` instead of `${user.home}`.